# Creating a loop that sums columns of multiple .CSV files in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, sum

I have 12 .csv files with monthly energy usage which looks like this:

```
Time;E_TotalKwh;E_TodayKwh
01-01-2014;2211.248;4.549
02-01-2014;2212.607;1.359
03-01-2014;2214.048;1.441
04-01-2014;2215.478;1.430
05-01-2014;2221.190;5.712
06-01-2014;2222.372;1.182
```

What I want is a PowerShell script that reads the 12 files for every month, calculates that sum of the "E_TodayKwh" column for every single month and saves the output as a seperate file (so a file with just the sum of the Kwh of that month)

What I tried is:

```
$SourceLocation = "C:\Projects\Jr_2014"
$DestinationLocation = "C:\Projects\Total_Jr_2014"

Get-ChildItem $SourceLocation -File | ForEach-Object{
Get-Content | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";" | Measure-Object "E_TodayKwh" -Sum 
$Month = Join-Path $DestinationLocation $($_.BaseName.split('-')[1])
If (!(Test-path $Month)) {mkdir $Month|Out-Null}
  $_|Move-Item -Destination $Month}
```

But this gets the following message:

> cmdlet Get-Content at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for
> the following parameters: Path[0]:

So I assume that I somehow have to specify a path for the Get-Content command, but because I want to do it for a loop I can't specify just one path, because I want the script to go through all 12 files in the sourcefolder

Is there anyone that could help me with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: PLEASE do not post images of sample data. >>> Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: for the error itself, you are NOT _in a pipeline_ at that point ... you are starting a NEW one that is embedded in the 1st one.

Comment: Ah, so I can use a wildcard! Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome! [*grin*]  i would likely use `Get-Content -Path $_.FullName`, but you can use a wildcard if you really want.

Comment: Ah gotcha, that's even better :-)

Comment: Either what @Lee_Dailey says, or change `Get-Content |...` -> `$_ |Get-Content |...`